# getJson not sending null values

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I am doing a JSON call to a SQL database and a stored procedure.  I have fields that are the parameters for the stored procedure, and they may or may not have values, but when they are null, the null isn't getting sent, it's sending nothing.  I would have expected the see nulls, when I look in my javascript model I do see nulls.  I'm not sure what I need to do differently?

Here is part of my code:

```
for (var i = 0, len = dsModelChanges.length; i < len; i++) {
    $.getJSON(Helpers.toServicesUrl("/PostupdateBatchUsersSchools"),
    {

        userName: WSIPCContext.UserName,
        districtId: WSIPCContext.DistrictId,
        UserToUpdate: 'lhedman', // dsModelChanges[i].Username,
        SchoolCode1: dsModelChanges[i].SchoolCode1,
        Selected1: dsModelChanges[i].Selected1,
        SchoolCode2: null,
        Selected2: null,
```

Here is part of what my request looks like when I don't hard-code the null values.  This shows that the values for "2" are just sending nothing.

```
ClientBin/WSIPC-Services-Web-WSIPCSPService.svc/json/PostupdateBatchUsersSchools?userName=wise%5Clhedman&districtId=2&UserToUpdate=lhedman&SchoolCode1=422&Selected1=true&SchoolCode2= &Selected2=&SchoolCode3=null&Selected3=null
```

Hardcoding the value to null works in that the request succeeds, but won't work of course because I may have a valid value in that field.  I tried doing a toString, but found out that doesn't work on null values.

I can loop through my data and set fields to "null" if they are, but I really think there must be a better way.

What things should I be looking at?

Editing to add more info: (2/4/14)
I've looked at the interaction with my stored procedure, and it seems like the string values are fine with nothing being sent, I added code to set them to null if nothing is sent.

The issue are fields that are defined as "bit" in the stored procedure, and "bool" in my javascript.  I tried similar code to sent them to "0" and then "false" in the stored procedure, but that's not working.  I can hard-code them in the JavaScript to "false" and that works, but seems clunky.

Snippet from my sproc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.updateBatchUsersSchools
(

@Username VARCHAR(100),
@DistrictId INT,
@UserToUpdate varchar(100),
@SchoolCode1 varchar(10) = null,
@Selected1 bit = 0,
```

Comment: Are you able to change your Stored Procedure? A possible work around could be changing it to accept the string 'NULL' instead. Does the incoming json data require you to precisely use null or can you post-process it?

Comment: How does your html look like?